# Averaging over specified time period

Tags: pandas, time, average, python-xarray

I opened multiple netcdfs (each one corresponds to an hour 0-30hr) with xr.open_mfdataset('*.nc'). Now I have an extra dimension (time). I am considering one of my variables(u,v,w). I want to average u (time: 30 z: 200 y: 100 x: 100) over 24 hours instead of the whole time period I have. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking questions try to avoid providing narrative details about the problem. All you seem to be asking is how to calculate a daily average? Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! 
Yeah exactly, but my time range is 30 hr. How do it do that?

Comment: I don't follow. You have opened it in xarray. Based on the question there should be 24 hours in the day. Where does 30 come in?

Comment: My model runs for 30 hr and it produces 1 netcdf per hour. Then i read them all together with xarray. What i would is to take the mean over 24 hr, instead of 30 hr. Is that possible?

Comment: You have opened this as a multi-file dataset. Are the times not coming in correctly? I'm not sure what you mean by "Now I have an extra dimension (time)". Was time not in the original file?

Comment: Hi again! As i wrote before, each netcdf corresponds to 1hr. So time is constant in every single netcdf, time=1. That is why, when i read them all together i got time=30 . The issue remains, is it possible to average over 24 hr and not 30 hr?

Comment: I am confused. If you only want the first 24 hours, why are you reading everything in? I recommend going through the documentation of xarray, which explains clearly how time should be set up in a dataset

Comment: Are you looking for 30 rolling 24hr averages, or resampled so you have two values, the average of the first day and the average of the second day? Or do you want to average the first 24 hours and ignore the remaining 6 hours?

Comment: If you just want to select the first 24 values along the time dim and then average them, you can simply do `ds.isel(time=slice(None, 24)).mean(dim='time')`. Is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: I want to average the first 24 hours and ignore the remaining 6

Comment: Ok. Does the code I posted work?

Comment: And if I want to select the last 10 or 20 instead of the first? How does that work?

Comment: Have you looked at the xarray docs? .isel is a pretty intuitive, well documented method.

Comment: Yeah never mind

Answer (score 3):

To select the first 24 observations along the time dim, you can use [`.isel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.isel.html), e.g.:

```py
ds24 = ds.isel(time=range(24))
```

See the xarray docs on [indexing and selecting data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html) for more options and examples.

Now, you can average over the time dim:

```py
ds24.mean(dim='time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some simple test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import datetime
# ---------------------
# let us make test serie:
N = 30;
datesout = np.array([datetime.datetime(2022,10,23,0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds = nn*3600) for nn in range(N)])
serieout = np.array([10 + nn for nn in range(N) ]);
# let us save netcdf:
dsout = xr.Dataset(data_vars=dict(someserie=(["time"], serieout)),coords=dict(time=datesout),attrs=dict(description="Test data."))
dsout.to_netcdf('test.nc')
# ---------------------
# let us make daily average:
with xr.open_dataset('test.nc') as ncin:
    # let us calculate daily means:
    dfmeanout = ncin.groupby("time.day").mean()
    # -----------------------------------------
    # keep only the first day:
    dfmeanout = dfmeanout.isel(day=0)
    # -----------------------------------------
    print('Got value: ',dfmeanout.values)
# --------------------------------------------
# simple test:
expected_mean = np.sum(np.array([vv+10 for vv in range(24)]))/24
print('Correct mean is : ',expected_mean)
# ---------------------------------------------
```